# Retrieve current price for currentr trading pairs in the spot market of binance

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to obtain current price for all currently trading usdt pair in binance, i use this piece of code but i get all prices, even of delisted pairs and i do not know how this is possible, and how to restrict to currently trading pairs:

```
def get_price(PAIR_WITH):
    '''Return the current price for all coins on binance'''

    initial_price = {}
    prices = client.get_all_tickers()

    for coin in prices:

        # only Return USDT pairs and exlcude margin symbols like BTCDOWNUSDT
        if PAIR_WITH in coin['symbol'] and all(item not in coin['symbol'] for item in FIATS):
            initial_price[coin['symbol']] = { 'price': coin['price'], 'time': datetime.now()}

    return initial_price

usdtprices = get_price(PAIR_WITH = 'USDT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get it using the Binance API

```
import requests
import json
import re
from pprint import pprint

payload={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
markets = json.loads(response.text)
active = {}
for market in markets['symbols']:
    symbol = market['symbol']
    status = market['status']
    active[symbol] = status == 'TRADING'

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr"

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
tickers = json.loads(response.text)

prices = {}
for ticker in tickers:
    symbol = ticker['symbol']
    isUSDT = re.search("USDT$", symbol)
    if (isUSDT and active[symbol]):
        prices[symbol] = ticker['lastPrice']

pprint(prices)
```

You can get examples of all the binance requests using their [postman examples](https://github.com/binance/binance-api-postman) and exporting the code

---

You can also use [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt), it's a library that acts like an SDK for about 120 exchanges, and then you can use the same code for any of those exchanges, it also handles signature and precision limits and stuff like that, they have a bunch of examples inside `ccxt/examples`

```
import ccxt
from pprint import pprint

exchange = ccxt.binance({})

tickers = exchange.fetch_tickers()

prices = {}
for symbol, ticker in tickers.items():
    market = exchange.market(symbol)
    if market['quote'] == 'USDT' and market['active'] == True:
        prices[symbol] = ticker['close']

pprint(prices)
```

---

Both these examples return the most recent price that the asset was traded at, but you can replace `close` with `bid` or `ask` if you want the current limit prices that people are asking, or replace `lastPrice` with `bidPrice` or `askPrice`

---

And you could probably just use `re` to filter against `BEAR`, `DOWN`, `BULL` but not sure about `UP` because you might exclude some normal markets